# How to stop Pulse() function (Python 2.7, wxPython, EnhancedStatusBar)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I am trying to implement a progress bar for a wxPython GUI. I made use of the EnhancedStatusBar (http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/main/EnhancedStatusBar.html). My code looks as follows:

```
for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''): #Read stdout line by line
    self.gauge1.Pulse()
    wx.CallAfter(self.write_to_textctrl, line) #Appends line variable to TextCtrl
```

I tried doing  self.gauge1.Destroy() right outside of for loop, but it didnt work. So how do I make Pulse function to stop when it stops reading stdout

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your process is not ending. You should add a check to see if `line` is empty and break out of the loop there. Then you can call `Destroy()` on your gauge.

Note that wxPython also has `wx.Gauge` and `PyGauge` in addition to the widget you mentioned. You might want to try one of those as well.

Comment: Another error showed up when I used Destroy(). Here it is:     raise PyDeadObjectError(self.attrStr % self._name)
PyDeadObjectError: The C++ part of the Gauge object has been deleted, attribute access no longer allowed. How do I overcome this error?

Comment: Don't store the string as an attribute of the Gauge class. Make it an attribute of the parent or grab it before you destroy the gauge.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a simple status bar with a progress bar in it, interacting with a subprocess calling `ping` as an example.
Hopefully, you will get some mileage out of it.

```
import wx
import subprocess
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Statusbar progress')
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        start_btn = wx.Button(panel, label='Start')
        start_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStart)
        stop_btn = wx.Button(panel, label='Stop')
        stop_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStop)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnExit)
        btn_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        btn_sizer.Add(start_btn)
        btn_sizer.Add(stop_btn)
        panel.SetSizer(btn_sizer)
        self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar(3)
        self.text1 = wx.StaticText(self.statusbar,-1,("Static text"))
        self.text2 = wx.StaticText(self.statusbar,-1,("Count Text"))
        self.progress_bar = wx.Gauge(self.statusbar, -1, style=wx.GA_HORIZONTAL|wx.GA_SMOOTH)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.text1, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.text2, 1, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.progress_bar, 2, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.statusbar.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show()
        self.progress_bar.SetRange(50)
        self.progress_bar.SetValue(0)

    def OnStart(self,event):
        self.text1.SetLabelText("Started")
        self.count = 0
        self.proc = subprocess.Popen(['ping','127.0.0.1','-i','0.2'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        while True:
            try:
                list_data = self.proc.stdout.readline()
            except:
                break
            if len(list_data) == 0:
                break
            self.progress_bar.Pulse()
            self.count+=1
            self.text2.SetLabelText("Count "+str(self.count))
            wx.Yield()

    def OnStop(self,event):
        self.text1.SetLabelText("Stopped")
        try:
            self.proc.kill()
        except:
            pass

    def OnExit(self,event):
        try:
            self.proc.kill()
        except:
            pass
        self.Destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

As you can see the `statusbar` is built with a sizer which allows for the positioning and relative sizing of the items.
I have added a `Start` button and now `Stop` does not terminate the program

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing an example. As I don't want to close my window, when I remove self.Destroy(), the progress bar still keeps moving like a marquee style progress bar. I want to make it stop as soon as the process ends. Is there anyway I could accomplish that?